# Convert HttpWebResponse contentType UTF-8 to UTF16?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, encoding, asp.net-web-api, utf-8

My `HttpWebResponse` contentType has encoding "UTF-8" . But I am loading response to XMLDocument it is throwing exception "There is no Unicode byte order mark. Cannot switch to Unicode.". XML has have encoding="utf-16" instead of "utf-8".

```
   HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(resp.GetResponseStream());
```

How can convert my `HttpWebResponse` from "utf-8" to "utf-16"?

### edit

[image]

[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5ZUC.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
using(var reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.Unicode)
using(XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(reader))
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xmlReader);
}
```

Comment: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.  I am getting this error

Comment: Can you show the first several bytes of your response? Perhaps you have got the response in encoding differ from UTF16 (Encodong.Unicode).

Comment: Please my response object in the image. Response is UTF-8 only. I changed your code little bit to `using(var reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), true))
                {
                     doc = XDocument.Load(reader);
                }` . But Deserialization throwing same error ` invalid. Line 1, position 1`

Comment: The problem in your XML encoding. It is in UTF16 encoding although your response encoded as UTF8. Am I understand you correctly?